# JSESSIONID from cookie to header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, restful-authentication

when using Spring Boot Security, by Bydefault `JSESSIONID` comes in the response header as a cookie when any API is invoked by the client.

```
http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
```

after getting the request authenticated. spring by Bydefault sends this JSESSIONID in response header cookie.

Then the client invokes subsequent API calls and sends this **JSESSIONID** in the request header as a cookie for API to be authenticated using **JSESSIONID** by Spring Boot Security.

I want to configure Spring Boot Security in such a way that Spring Boot does not send `JSESSIONID` as a cookie header, but instead sends `JSESSIONID` in the header as **`JSESSIONID`**:**`<JSESSIONID-value>`**.

then when the client invokes the next Spring Boot Security process this **JSESSIONID** from the header identifies if the session is already authenticated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @dcolazin edited to include more details. hope now it has required information that you looking for.

Comment: assuming embedded server as tomcat, i think it looks for session info from cookie. There is a provision to customize to read from http header by creating a new Valve class (by implementing org.apache.catalina.Valve interface) and configuring this new Valve class in tomcat's context.xml file. May I know why we need the JSESSIONID as one of the Header instead being part of cookie?

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian this question is part of a larger solution I am trying to build. Maybe you could guide me in the right direction (I am really new to Spring Boot) 
in short

trying to build API for Mobile clients so for example /signon API and then /info

the client gets authenticated using /signon and gets an auth In response. next call /info client sends this auth code in the header.

I know there is JWT but I don't want to implement that. also, I want to leverage Spring Secuirty authentication mechanism using JSESSIONID. I don't want to bypass it.